# Undefined reference to "Class::method" C++?

Tags: c++

I'm not sure if this problem is with my IDE, but I tried both Code::Blocks and Visual Studio with the project, so I don't think it is.

My main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Hello.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Hello firstMan;

    firstMan.greeting ();
    firstMan.goodbye ();
    firstMan.goodbye ();
}
```

My Hello.h:

```
#ifndef HELLO_H_INCLUDED
#define HELLO_H_INCLUDED

class Hello
{
    public:
        void greeting ();
        void goodbye ();
};

#endif // HELLO_H_INCLUDED
```

And my class file Hi.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Hello.h"

using namespace std;

void Hello::greeting ()
{
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
}

void Hello::goodbye ()
{
    cout << "Bye" << endl;
}
```

I've just started C++, so my apologies if this is a simple error or just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine.

It seems that you did not add `Hi.cpp` to your IDE project.

It's strange that you didn't call it `Hello.cpp` - do you have a file of *that* name (perhaps empty) that you're building instead?